# Android Studio error, CPU does not support VT-x and NX

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

My CPU supports AMD Virtualization technology but still Android Studio gives error that my CPU does not support VT-x and NX. Any help?

Comment: What's your CPU ?

Comment: @LeoR. Its AMD a6-7310

Comment: @LeoR. Its AMD a6-7310

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc, VT-x is an Intel Virtualization Technology, so you can't suppot this technologie with an AMD processor.

The second point, NX , is a feature of a processor that helps to protect your PC from attacks by malicious software. When this feature is not enabled and you try to run certain emulators in android studio, you will get an error message like this.

You need to restart your computer, enter BIOS, in case of AMD processors, you will see the NX flag. If that is not enabled, toggle the option and enable it.

Comment: Thankss !! But I have already enabled Virtualization Technology in BIOS. I don't see any NX flag. What do I do?

Comment: The NX or XD flag is not available in all the BIOS programs. Many manufacturers are not showing this option in the BIOS.
Maybe your CPU does not support NX/XD flag. This is modern feature introduced in newer versions of the CPU and may not be available in old versions of the CPUs

Comment: Thank u for replying..
So... Isn&#39;t there any chance of NX being available for this CPU?
I mean it supports VT so it must not be a very old CPU..

Comment: If you have a correct graphic card you can use an alternative Android Emulator, like Genymotion for example.

Comment: Alright thanks man.. I think I'll have to manage a better laptop.... Anyway thank u!

Comment: a Desktop pc will be better ^^

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio **Virtual Device Testing** requires ***virtualization*** AND ***Hypervisor*** with Windows os, running on an AMD processor.

**Control Panel:** You need to enable 'Hyper-V' and 'Windows Hypervisor Platform' BOTH. Open control Panel, search for 'Turn Windows features on or off', the tick the boxes for both the above features. This requires a restart. You can do the BIOS update on the same restart:

**BIOS:** Your CPU may have virtualization turned off (even if the cpu supports virtualization). (look up your CPU specs and look for the virtualization spec it should say AMD-V ).

Restart your PC, enter the BIOS (del or alt+f4 or f1), and enter 'advanced cpu' menu.  There toggle on 'virtualization' ( it may be called 'SVM mode' or 'AMD-V' ).  Then save and exit the BIOS.

**Android Studio:** Of course install all the packages that Android Studio asks for for the AVD you choose.

Also I installed ALL of the tools (Settings->Appearance & Behaviour->System Settings->Android SDK) under the tab 'SDK Tools' in Android Studio.

**That worked for me.**  It took a while to find the solution.  But that did it.