# Running Android Emulator on MacBook Pro M3 Pro: 'CPU does not support VT-x' Error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, emulation, macos-sonoma

[image]
Running Android Emulator on MacBook Pro M3 Pro: 'CPU does not support VT-x' Error in Android Studio.

I have tried to update the latest version of apple version of android studio, but I still can't use emulator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Your CPU does not support VT-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541801/your-cpu-does-not-support-vt-x)

Comment: did u try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525669/android-studio-error-cpu-does-not-support-vt-x-and-nx